Is there a way to transpose rows to columns without grouping the data
I have a dictionary and I would like to convert the keys of the dictionary to column name and rows to its value.
For example:
Input:

Desired Output:

So far, I could explode the dictionary so that each row has a separate dictionary.

and next if I explode it again I get the below but I am not able to get these rows as columns

Thank you for your help

if you know all the Map keys beforehand (for example: keys=["start","end","duration"]), then after your first explode, do a select with a list comprehension: df.select("ID", *[F.col('Timeframe')[k].alias(k) for k in keys])

@lihao Perfect! This works..Thanks.

Given you have an ArrayType with a struct, the best way of achieving your result is using explode_outer (you get the null values for 456 with it) or explode if you wanna skip nulls. Then, after exploding, simply use the "." notation in the columns to create the transposed like you need. Here's an example below - I ran in Databricks so if you are running locally you'll need to set up the spark context.
Performance Tip: Be extra careful with explode operations they're usually costly, so consider always downsizing your data exploding always the essential for your needs.
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

timeframe_schema = ArrayType(
    StructType([
        StructField("start", LongType(), True),
        StructField("end", LongType(), True),
        StructField("duration", IntegerType(), True)
    ])
)


df_schema = StructType([
    StructField("ID", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Timeframe", timeframe_schema, True)
])

data = [
    (123, [{"start": 123456, "end": 567898, "duration": 2}]),
    (456, None),
    (789, [{"start": 1323456, "end": 4567898, "duration": 40}, {"start": 654665, "end": 8922341, "duration": 60}])
]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, df_schema)


# Explode the Timeframe ArrayType column
df_exploded = df.withColumn("Timeframe", explode_outer(col("Timeframe")))

# Select and rename columns to flatten the structure
df_transposed = df_exploded.select(
    col("ID"),
    col("Timeframe.start").alias("start"),
    col("Timeframe.end").alias("end"),
    col("Timeframe.duration").alias("duration")
)

df_transposed.display()

